# How to run mongo shell using mongos command?

Tags: mongodb

I have two versions of `mongodb`, 2.4.3 and 2.6.0. I am able to start both the versions on different ports, but while running it using **./mongos** I get an error:

```
BadValue error: no args for --configdb
```

How can I resolve my issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`mongos` program](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongos/) is not the shell it is the command to run a router process in a sharded environment (it stands for "MongoDB Shard").  You want the [`mongo` command](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongo/) to launch a shell.